# How to Filter file from directory by using File name using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var GetFileByFileName = Directory.GetFiles(SourceFilePath)
                                       .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
                                       .Where(x => x.Name==SourceFileName)
                                       .Take(1)
                                       .ToArray();
```

This is my code for fetch file by Specified File name.Here i am using array . In here SOURCEFILENAME is an string variable which having the file name.but it is not working.i could get all files from directory.but i need only one file from directory based on the SOURCEFILENAME.? Please help me..Thank You. .

Comment: the code has no issue check it you are looking something wrong, what is the SourceFileName you passed ?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What result are you getting?

Comment: it took very first file from directory

Comment: what you passed in SourceFileName?

Comment: string SourceFileName=myphoto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to use the way what you currently used then you have implement be in below mentioned way

```
 var GetFileByFileName = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Re\reactdemo")
                                       .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
                                       .Where(x => x.Name == "package.json")
                                       .Take(1)
                                       .ToArray();
```

check your SourcePath should look like what I have hard coded in code and your source file should be with extension

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, and should work.

Alternatively, you can do it without `Linq`. `Directory.GetFiles` has an overload that accepts the file search pattern, where you can pass your file name.

```
var fileInfo = Directory.GetFiles(SourceFilePath, SourceFileName);
```

Where, for example

```
var SourceFilePath = @"C:\MyBackUp\Files";
var SourceFileName = @"MyTextFile.txt";
```

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to search among all files using linq, when you have both filename and the path? Your linq query is comparing == SourceFileName which is what you will get by directly seeking file using standard [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operation.

```
var file = Path.Combine(SourceFilePath, SourceFileName);

//check if exists
if (File.Exists(file))
{
  // open your file to read it as needed
  // e.g. reading as text:
  var content = File.ReadAllText(file);

}
```